# Different partials for different type of content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Post model I've got an attribute like "content_type". Posts of different types should be displayed in different way on the same list. For now I've got only one idea to do this:

```
    <%= 
        @posts.each do |d|
            if d.content_type == "NormalStory"
                render :partial => 'posts/normal', :locals => { :content => d }
            elsif d.content_type == "FotoStory"
                render :partial => 'posts/foto', :locals => { :content => d}
            elsif d.content_type "VideoStory"
                render :partial => 'posts/video', :locals => { :content => d }
            end
        end
    %>
```

Could you please recommend me something more 'elegant'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a helper which inflects the partial from the `content_type`, something like:

```
def render_post(post)
  template = post.content_type.sub(/Story$/, '').downcase
  render :partial => "posts/#{template}", :locals => { :content => post }
end
```

Comment: I second this approach. You're basically setting a convention for the `content_type` value and name of the partial, so you can add more types without touching the code. The other answers all require you to edit the code when adding a new content type. Although, I would look into `ActionController::Responder` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) before writing a helper method.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%  @posts.each do |d| %>
<%=   render :partial => get_path(d.content_type), :locals => { :content => d } %>
<%  end %>
```

In helpers (app/helpers/) you should define this helper method

```
def get_path(content_type)
  case content_type
    when "NormalStory" 
      'posts/normal'
    when "FotoStory"
      'posts/foto'
    when "VideoStory"
      'posts/video'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
<%=
@posts.each do |d|
if d.content_type == "NormalStory"
         view_name = "normal"   
elsif d.content_type == "FotoStory"
         view_name = "foto"
elsif d.content_type "VideoStory"
         view_name = "video"
end
render :partial => "posts/"+view_name, :locals => { :content => d }
end
%>
```